# How to make Julia Code more Efficient? Currently it is performing even worse than Python

Tags: python, performance, julia

I am new to Julia and have been experimenting with it as I got to know that it has amazing performances. But I am still to experience those promised performances. I have tried many methods for enhancing performance described in the book "JULIA HIGH PERFORMANCE", which has made the code a little bit less readable. But still, my python code is much faster than my Julia code, at least 3x faster for the benchmark case. 
Either I am doing something very wrong with the code which must be a sin in Julia or its that Julia just can't do it. Please prove me wrong about the later.

What I am trying to do in the code is assign distinct balls into distinct boxes with a maximum and minimum limit to the capacity of each box. The order in which balls are placed in the box also matters. I need to generate all possible assignments with the given constraints in minimum possible time.

PYTHON CODE:

```
import itertools
import time

max_balls = 5
min_balls = 0

def get_assignments(balls, boxes, assignments=[[]]):
    all_assignments = []
    upper_ball_limit = len(balls)
    if upper_ball_limit > max_balls:
        upper_ball_limit = max_balls

    n_boxes = len(boxes)
    lower_ball_limit = len(balls) - upper_ball_limit * (n_boxes - 1)
    if lower_ball_limit < min_balls:
        lower_ball_limit = min_balls

    if len(boxes) == 0:
        raise Exception("No delivery boys found")

    elif len(boxes) == 1:
        for strategy in itertools.permutations(balls, upper_ball_limit):
            #             valid = evaluate_strategy(strategy, db_id)
            for subplan in assignments:
                subplan_copy = subplan[:]
                box_id = boxes[0]
                subplan_copy.append((box_id, strategy))
                all_assignments.append(subplan_copy)
        return all_assignments
    else:
        box_id = boxes[0]
        for i in range(lower_ball_limit, upper_ball_limit+ 1):
            for strategy in itertools.permutations(balls, i):
                temp_plans = []
                for subplan in assignments:
                    subplan_copy = subplan[:]
                    subplan_copy.append((box_id, strategy))
                    temp_plans.append(subplan_copy)
                    remaining_balls = set(balls).difference(strategy)
                    remaining_boxes = list(set(boxes).difference([box_id]))
                    if remaining_balls:
                        all_assignments.extend(get_assignments(remaining_balls, remaining_boxes, temp_plans))
                    else:
                        all_assignments.extend(temp_plans)
        return all_assignments

balls = range(1, 9)
boxes = [1, 2, 3, 4]

t = time.time()
all_assignments = get_assignments(balls, boxes)

print('Number of assignments: %s' % len(all_assignments))
print('Time taken: %s' % (time.time()-t))
```

And here is my attempt at writing the JULIA CODE for the above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

using Combinatorics

const max_balls=5
const min_balls=0

function plan_assignments(balls::Vector{Int32}, boxes ; plans=[Vector{Tuple{Int32,Array{Int32,1}}}(length(boxes))])
const n_boxes = length(boxes)
const n_balls = length(balls)
const n_plans = length(plans)

if n_boxes*max_balls < n_balls
  print("Invalid Inputs: Number of balls exceed the number of boxes.")
end

all_plans = Vector{Tuple{Int32,Array{Int32,1}}}[]
upper_box_limit = n_balls
if upper_box_limit > max_balls
    upper_box_limit = max_balls
end
lower_box_limit = n_balls - upper_box_limit * (n_boxes-1)

if lower_box_limit < min_balls
    lower_box_limit = min_balls
end

if n_boxes == 1
    box_id = boxes[1]
    @inbounds for strategy in Combinatorics.permutations(balls, upper_box_limit)
        @inbounds for subplan in plans
            subplan = subplan[:]
            subplan[tn_boxes - n_boxes + 1] = (box_id, strategy)
            all_plans = push!(all_plans, subplan)
        end
    end
    return all_plans

else
    box_id = boxes[1]
    @inbounds for i in lower_box_limit:upper_box_limit
        @inbounds for strategy in Combinatorics.permutations(balls, i)
            temp_plans = Array{Vector{Tuple{Int32,Array{Int32,1}}},1}(n_plans)
            # temp_plans = []

            @inbounds for (i,subplan) in zip(1:n_plans, plans)
                subplan = subplan[:]
                subplan[tn_boxes - n_boxes + 1] = (box_id, strategy)
                temp_plans[i] = subplan
                # subplan = push!(subplan, (db_id, strategy))
                # temp_plans = push!(temp_plans, subplan)

                remaining_balls = filter((x) -> !(x in strategy), balls)
                remaining_boxes = filter((x) -> x != box_id , boxes)

                if length(remaining_balls) > 0
                  @inbounds for plan in plan_assignments(remaining_balls, remaining_boxes, plans=temp_plans)
                    push!(all_plans, plan)
                  end
                    # append!(all_plans, plan_assignments(remaining_orders, remaining_delivery_boys, plans=temp_plans))
                else
                  @inbounds for plan in temp_plans
                    push!(all_plans, plan)
                  end
                    # append!(all_plans, temp_plans)

                end
            end
        end
    end
    return all_plans
end
end

balls = Int32[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
boxes = Int32[1,2,3,4]

const tn_boxes = length(boxes)

@timev all_plans = plan_assignments(balls, boxes)
print(length(all_plans))
```

My benchmark timings are as follows:

For Python:

```
Number of assignments: 5040000
Time taken: 22.5003659725
```

For Julia: (This is while discounting the compilation time.)

```
76.986338 seconds (122.94 M allocations: 5.793 GB, 77.01% gc time)
elapsed time (ns): 76986338257
gc time (ns):      59287603693
bytes allocated:   6220111360
pool allocs:       122932049
non-pool GC allocs:10587
malloc() calls:    11
realloc() calls:   18
GC pauses:         270
full collections:  28
```

Comment: 77% time spent on the garbage collection... it seems like the issue is that you are creating tons of objects. CPython avoids such big hits by using reference counting together with the GC. Note that 23% of 77 seconds is about 17 seconds, so Julia would be faster than CPython, if you do not count the time spent in gc... Unfortunately I don't know Julia, so I can't tell you why so much time is spent in the gc.

Comment: Is `all_plans = push!(all_plans, subplan)` doing what you want?

Comment: Do you need to take a copy of subplan in `subplan = subplan[:]`?

Comment: @daycaster Yes it does the job, although I understand that assignment operator is redundant.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley Yes, I do need to take the copy of subplan as in Julia objects are called by reference as in Python. Basically say a subplans is given by [1] and strategies are [2,3,4,5] then I need to create all combinations [1,2], [1,3], [1,4] and [1,5] and store them as well in another array. If I do not take a copy I will keep mutating the same object.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the data structure for some simple example like [1,2,3] and [1,2,3]? I see some #undef. What should the output look like? Also, the data structure you have seems too complicated.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders #undef comes because some boxes might not be assigned any balls. Earlier I was using an empty array to store these values using(push!) but later optimised that to a fixed length array, which supposedly will be more efficient. Earlier implementation wouldn't have those #undef values, as the length of the array will be equal to the number of elements present in it. 
I have defined those complex data structure so that Julia doesn't have to infer type info from the data, which supposedly again reduces the performance.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders continued... It is just a simple Array of (fixed length Array of Vectors) and Vector contains an Integer and another Array. I have been working on it for last 2 days. Obviously, I have looked at the outputs for simpler examples. Just posted the inputs that I have, because they make the difference in timing prominent and are computable in a reasonable time.

Comment: have you tried using the [profiler](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/profile/)? have you ensured that your code is type-stable, perhaps with the [`code_warntype`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/performance-tips/#code-warntype) macro? these and @Bakuriu's comment about garbage collection are all important performance analysis considerations.

Comment: Extreme amounts of over allocation and large swaths of time used by garbage collection are warning signs for type instability (since everything has to be boxed, resulting in a bunch of temporaries). What does `@code_warntype` say? Can you use `ProfileView` to show where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I don't think the type instabilities matter. Just filling your data structure with zeros needs 10 s on my PC while your method needs 44 s. In both cases it shows about 70% gc time. On the other hand, `zeros(5040000, 4, 8)` takes only 0.3 s.  So it seems that in Julia a large `Array` of small `Array`s is not very fast.

Comment: @KevinLKeys I used the profiler but couldn't figure out how I could use that, as the profile for my code was itself very long and being a beginner, I couldn't understand much there. Also, I have used 'code_warntype', what I could figure from there was that perhaps Combinatorics.permutations function itself is not type stable. So my code can't be type-stable.

Comment: Irrelevant: `len(boxes)` should be replaced with `n_boxes` in the `if`, `elif`.

Comment: Same goes for `len(balls)`. You might be able to post the Python code (and the Julia, separately)  in CodeReview. Check their rules before doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is another version in Julia, a little bit more idiomatic and modified to avoid recursion and some allocations:

```
using Iterators
using Combinatorics

histograms(n,m) = [diff([0;x;n+m]).-1 for x in combinations([1:n+m-1;],m-1)]

good_histograms(n,m,minval,maxval) = 
  [h for h in histograms(n,m) if all(maxval.>=h.>=minval)]

typealias PlanGrid Matrix{SubArray{Int,1,Array{Int,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int}},true}}

function assignmentplans(balls,boxes,minballs,maxballs)
  nballs, nboxes = length(balls),length(boxes)
  nperms = factorial(nballs)
  partslist = good_histograms(nballs,nboxes,minballs,maxballs)
  plans = PlanGrid(nboxes,nperms*length(partslist))
  permutationvector = vec([balls[p[i]] for i=1:nballs,p in permutations(balls)])
  i1 = 1
  for parts in partslist
    i2 = 0
    breaks = [(x[1]+1:x[2]) for x in partition(cumsum([0;parts]),2,1)]
    for i=1:nperms
      for j=1:nboxes
        plans[j,i1] = view(permutationvector,breaks[j]+i2)
      end
      i1 += 1
      i2 += nballs
    end
  end
  return plans
end
```

For timing we get:

```
julia> assignmentplans([1,2],[1,2],0,2)   # a simple example
2×6 Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},2}:
 Int64[]  Int64[]  [1]  [2]  [1,2]    [2,1]  
 [1,2]    [2,1]    [2]  [1]  Int64[]  Int64[]

julia> @time plans = assignmentplans([1:8;],[1:4;],0,5);
  8.279623 seconds (82.28 M allocations: 2.618 GB, 14.07% gc time)

julia> size(plans)
(4,5040000)

julia> plans[:,1000000]                    # sample ball configuration
4-element Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},1}:
 Int64[]    
 [7,3,8,2,5]
 [4]        
 [6,1]
```

Timings, of course, vary per setup, but this should be much faster. It is not exactly an apples to apples comparison, but it calculates the same stuff. Timing on the poster's (or others') machines are welcome in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I guess the takeaway from this could be that Julia is only fast if written in right manner. It's not fast universally disregarding the way you write it. Though I still have to write the solution you have given, in python and compare to give a final verdict. BTW I am getting `14.367281 seconds (82.29 M allocations: 2.618 GB, 52.42% gc time)`  on my Macbook Pro 2015 with 16 GB memory and i7 processor.  Don't why `gc time` is so much while you are getting only 14%. Any clues?

Comment: @manofsins Yes, and I think the other takeaways are that translations between languages ought to search for idiomatic equivalents rather than literal conversions, and that improving the algorithm can produce more benefits than trying to speed up an inefficient one. (I still think your original version made too many assignments, though...)

Comment: "Julia is only fast if written in the right manner", yes and no. *Bad* code will hit bottlenecks on *any* language, and effective, non-standard, language-specific optimisations exist in all. There's a famous blogpost that 'beats' julia using python with lots of arcane python hacks. Julia's claim is that *standard*, unvectorised code is faster (in fact, recommended!) in julia compared to *standard* python / matlab code (vectorised or not).  But yes, standard good practices still matter (e.g. avoiding expensive re-allocations), and no, intentionally inefficient code won't magically "speed up".

Comment: The new code needs 7 s on my PC. After writing type-stable versions of `permutations`, `combinations`, and `partition`, and adding a few explicit types to some comprehensions in the code, I can get a runtime of 1.5 s with about 50% gc time. Is it ok to paste so many lines of code? Probably, I should open one or two pull requests instead.

Comment: @tim Nice. The type instability of `permutations` was indeed an annoyance. Can you put the code in a pastebin (http://pastebin.com) and link in a comment, or just add another answer, as this is interesting and relevant.

Comment: @tim please do share the type-stable version of the codes.

Answer (score 5):

I made a few minor changes to the code of Dan Getz in order to make it type-stable. The main problem was that `Combinatorics.permutations` and `Iterators.partition` are not type-stable, so I had to write type-stable versions of these as well (my change to `Combinatorics.combinations` was actually unnecessary)

```
import Base: start, next, done, eltype, length, size
import Base: iteratorsize, SizeUnknown, IsInfinite, HasLength

import Combinatorics: factorial, combinations

# Copied from Combinatorics
# Only one small change in the `nextpermutation` method

immutable Permutations{T}
    a::T
    t::Int
end

eltype{T}(::Type{Permutations{T}}) = Vector{eltype(T)}

length(p::Permutations) = (0 <= p.t <= length(p.a))?factorial(length(p.a), length(p.a)-p.t):0

"""
Generate all permutations of an indexable object. Because the number of permutations can be very large, this function returns an iterator object. Use `collec
t(permutations(array))` to get an array of all permutations.
"""
permutations(a) = Permutations(a, length(a))

"""
Generate all size t permutations of an indexable object.
"""
function permutations(a, t::Integer)
    if t < 0
        t = length(a) + 1
    end
    Permutations(a, t)
end

start(p::Permutations) = [1:length(p.a);]
next(p::Permutations, s) = nextpermutation(p.a, p.t ,s)

function nextpermutation(m, t, state)
    s = copy(state)                     # was s = copy(s) a few lines down
    perm = [m[s[i]] for i in 1:t]
    n = length(s)
    if t <= 0
        return(perm, [n+1])
    end
    if t < n
        j = t + 1
        while j <= n &&  s[t] >= s[j]; j+=1; end
    end
    if t < n && j <= n
        s[t], s[j] = s[j], s[t]
    else
        if t < n
            reverse!(s, t+1)
        end
        i = t - 1
        while i>=1 && s[i] >= s[i+1]; i -= 1; end
        if i > 0
            j = n
            while j>i && s[i] >= s[j]; j -= 1; end
            s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
            reverse!(s, i+1)
        else
            s[1] = n+1
        end
    end
    return(perm, s)
end

done(p::Permutations, s) = !isempty(s) && max(s[1], p.t) > length(p.a) ||  (isempty(s) && p.t > 0)  

# Copied from Iterators
# Returns an `Array` of `Array`s instead of `Tuple`s now

immutable Partition{I}
    xs::I
    step::Int
    n::Int

end

iteratorsize{T<:Partition}(::Type{T}) = SizeUnknown()

eltype{I}(::Type{Partition{I}}) = Vector{eltype(I)}

function partition{I}(xs::I, n::Int, step::Int = n)
    Partition(xs, step, n)
end

function start{I}(it::Partition{I})
    N = it.n
    p = Vector{eltype(I)}(N)
    s = start(it.xs)
    for i in 1:(N - 1)
        if done(it.xs, s)
            break
        end
        (p[i], s) = next(it.xs, s)
    end
    (s, p)
end

function next{I}(it::Partition{I}, state)
    N = it.n
    (s, p0) = state
    (x, s) = next(it.xs, s)
    ans = p0; ans[end] = x

    p = similar(p0)
    overlap = max(0, N - it.step)
    for i in 1:overlap
        p[i] = ans[it.step + i]
    end

    # when step > n, skip over some elements
    for i in 1:max(0, it.step - N)
        if done(it.xs, s)
            break
        end
        (x, s) = next(it.xs, s)
    end

    for i in (overlap + 1):(N - 1)
        if done(it.xs, s)
            break
        end

        (x, s) = next(it.xs, s)
        p[i] = x
    end

    (ans, (s, p))
end

done(it::Partition, state) = done(it.xs, state[1])

# Copied from the answer of Dan Getz
# Added types to comprehensions and used Vector{Int} instead of Int in vcat    

typealias PlanGrid Matrix{SubArray{Int,1,Array{Int,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int}},true}}

histograms(n,m) = [diff(vcat([0],x,[n+m])).-1 for x in combinations([1:n+m-1;],m-1)]

good_histograms(n,m,minval,maxval) = 
  Vector{Int}[h for h in histograms(n,m) if all(maxval.>=h.>=minval)]

minballs = 0
maxballs = 5

function assignmentplans(balls,boxes,minballs,maxballs)
  nballs, nboxes = length(balls),length(boxes)
  nperms = factorial(nballs)
  partslist = good_histograms(nballs,nboxes,minballs,maxballs)
  plans = PlanGrid(nboxes,nperms*length(partslist))
  permutationvector = vec([balls[p[i]] for i=1:nballs,p in permutations(balls)])
  i1 = 1
  for parts in partslist
    i2 = 0
    breaks = UnitRange{Int64}[(x[1]+1:x[2]) for x in partition(cumsum(vcat([0],parts)),2,1)]
    for i=1:nperms
      for j=1:nboxes
        plans[j,i1] = view(permutationvector,breaks[j]+i2)
      end
      i1 += 1
      i2 += nballs
    end
  end
  return plans
end

@time plans = assignmentplans(1:8, 1:4, 0, 5)
```

The result of the first run is (the timings vary a lot because of the gc)

```
  1.589867 seconds (22.02 M allocations: 1.127 GB, 46.50% gc time)
4×5040000 Array{SubArray{Int64,1,Array{Int64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true},2}:
 Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      …  [8,7,6,5,4]  [8,7,6,5,4]  [8,7,6,5,4]  [8,7,6,5,4]  [8,7,6,5,4]
 Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]         [1,3,2]      [2,1,3]      [2,3,1]      [3,1,2]      [3,2,1]    
 [1,2,3]      [1,2,3]      [1,2,3]      [1,2,3]      [1,2,3]      [1,2,3]         Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]    
 [4,5,6,7,8]  [4,5,6,8,7]  [4,5,7,6,8]  [4,5,7,8,6]  [4,5,8,6,7]  [4,5,8,7,6]     Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]      Int64[]
```

I didn't test the changes thoroughly. Also, I don't understand, why `s = copy(s)` works in `combinations` but not in `permutations`. Interestingly, there is only a negligible improvement if I try to make the original version type-stable (still > 40 s with 85% gc time).

Comment: Thanks tim. Is there a move to make type-stable combinatorics part of the standard packages? Feels like high priority stuff.

Comment: if you can write some tests to demonstrate the superiority of your version versus the current standard, then consider filing a pull request at the Combinatorics.jl repo!

Comment: I am just user and don't know much about the development of Julia. I guess, adding more features is also important and some of the current type-instabilities will go away with improvements in base, e.g., there is already a PR fixing `vcat` for mixed argument types. And for the rest, it is probably a good idea to report the issues or even fix them as a user. I just figured out how comfortable the latter is with `PkgDev.submit(pkgname)`.